# CPU gets hot ONLY at idle

Tags: cpu, overheating

I'm using an i5-10600K

When using Chrome or watching videos the temps are around the high 40s (no fan noise), when I stop everything the CPU fan powers up to near 100% and the temps get to the mid 60s.  **The *instant* I move the mouse the temps go back to the 40 again.**
I'm thinking this is an OS/software issue rather than an airflow/room temp/thermal paste issue correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some program is taking over when the computer is idle.
If you haven't installed any program for volunteering CPU power for some good cause,
then your computer might be infected.

For starters:

- Open the Task Manager
- Position to the Details tab
- Ensure that the column "CPU time" is visible
  (if not, right-click the column headers and choose "Select columns")
- Click the column to sort by descending order
- Let the computer idle and watch the screen until it gets hot
  (shorten the idle period if necessary).

This will tell you which program uses the CPU.
But if this is only the "System idle process", then more troubleshooting steps are
required.

Note: If it doesn't happen when the Task Manager is open, this means that the computer
is in fact infected and the virus is hiding itself (some viruses do that).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem of the above. after many tries I solved it by creating a new user on the PC.

it will take you time to move your files, but I guess it's better than re-formatting the windows or try expensive solutions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).